# How to enable scroll bar on share point list attachment page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-form

1. Create a SharePoint 2010 custom list
2. Go to custom list settings --> Add from existing site columns --> choose all columns and create
3. Click on 'Add new item' link 
   **Notice** that the **scroll bars** are **enabled**.
4. Click on 'Attach file'  button on ribbon.
   **Notice** that the **scroll bars** are **disabled**.
5. Attach file and click 'Ok' button
   **Notice** that the **scroll bars** are still **disabled**.

**Question:** Is there a way to enable the scroll bars all the time on SharePoinnt List NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx pages?

Answer (score 1):

By default scroll bars are active whenever the content is wider/longer than the fixed width/height of the container. Unless of course your branding overrides this.

How ever this can be achieved by changing `s4-workspace`'s css proterty `overflow-y` from `auto` to `visible`.